# Display image in PDF attachment in Email in c#

Tags: c#, image, pdf, base64, email-attachments

I am sending a PDF as an attachment in Email by using c#.

I am adding base64 images in that PDF and then send that PDF as an attachment in Email in c#.

But that added image not display in attached PDF when i received email.

How can i display base64 images in PDF? How can i achieve this functionality?

Please help.

Comment: Is your question is about how to add images to PDF files? How to encode PDF files using base64? To me your question is pretty unclear and lacks the code that provides context of what are you trying to do. Consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62166506/edit), rewording it, and adding the code you tried.

Comment: I am actually adding base64 image in PDF file. But when i received email, then attached PDF file not display that image. That's my problem. Can you help me in this?

Comment: (Besides Cleptus suggestion) Try to save your PDF in your local disk first, and check your image there. Example code: 
`using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(yourImageInBase64)))
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream("c:\some_path\filename.pdf", FileMode.Create))
  {
    memStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
  }`
If you don't see it, fix that first